# How to click on save as after right click anywhere on a webpage using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written the below code to save the webpage as html using selenium python. so far i have reached till opening a website then right click and but not getting how can i click on save as button as the cursor doesnt move after right click window and save as tab is on the 4th position from the top. can anyone pls help ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Actionchains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys

webdriver_service = Service('c:\\Path\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.chrome(options=options,service=webdriver_service)

url = "http://intranet.gs.com/equities/report"
driver.get(url)

# since there is no specific area for right click button so the user can right click anywhere on the entire webpage to save it 

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/bodytable[1]/tbody/tr/td")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(button).context_click(button).perform()
actions.move_to_element(button).context_click(button).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.Enter).perform()
actions.click()
```

Comment: that prompt is outside of the DOM.  (Selenium can't access it.  Only DOM-based right-click context menus would be available to Selenium.)  "Save As" is an option in a browser prompt.

Comment: then what is the solution in this case

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can only interact with a webpage in a browser. The right-click context menu is browser specific and outside Selenium's reach. If all you want is the page source, this code gets you what you want. Update the path and filename to whatever you need.

```
url = "http://intranet.gs.com/equities/report"
driver.get(url)
with open("source.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffc, it opens the website but then nothing happens

Comment: i dont not need page resource information, i need to save the webpage as html file in c drive

Comment: It saves the source as source.txt. You can change the extension to .html, if you want.